# Switch no identifica casos correctamente

Tags: javascript, nodejs

```js
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
    switch(card){
        case (2||3||4||5||6):
            count+=1;
            switch(count){
                case(count>-0.1):
                    count = count+" Bet";
                    console.log(count);
                    break;
                case(count<=0):
                    count = count+" Hold";
                    console.log(count);
                    break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        default:
            console.log("Change Me");
            break;
        }
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(4); cc(5); cc(6);
```

En este codigo para conteo de cartas de black-jack, el primer switch (linea 5) no identifica correctamente los casos para card, ejecuta default.
En el caso de este fragmento, debería mostrar "5 Bet"

Comment: El código debe ir _como texto, con formato_. ¿Ejecutaste paso a paso tu programa? ¿Estás seguro/a de la sintaxis que estás utilizando?

Comment: Si escribes el código te doy la solución :)

Comment: Tendrías que especificar que esperas que suceda en cada caso.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error amigo es que no estas usando el switch correctamente, en el caso que muestras es mejor poner una condicion, ya que para la mayoria de casos necesitas hacer el mismo codigo.

```
function cc(card){
        if(card === 2 || card === 3 || card === 4 || card === 5 || card === 6){
            count+=1;
            if(count > -0.1){
                count = count + "Bet"
            }else if(count <= 0){
                count = count + "Hold"
            }
        }else{
            console.log("Change me");
        }
    }
```

Quedaria algo asi, el switch se utiliza cuando tienes demaciadas condiciones, pero en este caso se te facilita mejor con el if

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un switch statement con múltiples options, debes corregir la sintaxis de la siguiente forma:

```
function cc(card) {
    switch(card){
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            count+=1;
            switch(count){
                case(count>-0.1):
                    count = count+" Bet";
                    console.log(count);
                    break;
                case(count<=0):
                    count = count+" Hold";
                    console.log(count);
                    break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Change Me");
            break;
        }
}
```

Fijate que si no quieres que se ejecute el código del último `default`, debes agregar un `break` antes... de lo contrario el default también se va a ejecutar, y por lo tanto se muestra el mensaje "Change Me". Fue lo primero que me pasó al intentar corregir el código.

Puedes encontrar más información en el siguiente link (Fijate el apartado: Operación única con múltiples casos):
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch.